# How can we count agents in a statechart based on their fill color in AnyLogic?

Tags: colors, state, anylogic, counting, agent-based-modeling

I am modelling an Agent based model in AnyLogic. I am trying to count the number of agents in a statechart with similer fill color as the agents will be assigned different fill colors as they enter different states using the `setFillColor()` command. I have tried the command `item.statechart.equals(Color.red)` but its not bringing up any value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest making use of a variable, even if it is a variable of type Color and rather count agents with the variable set to a specific color. It will be easier to count e.g
`agents.stream().filter(e -> colorVariable.equals(blue)).count()`

but you can also do this with the rectangle

`agents.stream().filter(e -> e.rectangle.getFillColor().equals(blue)).count()`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what element you fill the color with. If you have a rectangle in an and call `rectangle.setFillColor(blue)`, then you can count all agents using `item.rectangle.getFillColor().equals(blue)`

Note that you cannot count by the color of statechart states. For that, you can (and should) check if an agent is in a given state using `item.statechart.isStateActive(someState)`